# Cargar imagen en un servidor desde mi página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Desde hace un tiempo he estado buscando la manera de poder visualizar una imagen en mi página de la manera en la que adjunto en la imagen: [image]En la cual creo que lo que se hace es al seleccionarla de mi directorio local es subirla a un servidor y visualizarla desde ahí pero no sabría como hacer eso, así que les estaría muy agradecido si pudieran explicarme la manera de concretar este objetivo.

Comment: No veo que agregas una etiqueta o algo referente al lenguaje que utilizas en el servidor

Comment: Trabajo con PHP, Javascript y jQuery sin embargo me gustaría subirla usando jQuery o en su defecto Javascript

Comment: ¿Lo que deseas es ver la imagen en el navegador sin la necesidad de subirla a un servidor?

Comment: No, lo que busco es subirla a un servidor y desde ahí visualizarla sin necesidad de recargar la página

Comment: Haz investigado codificando la imagen a `base 64` y pasandole este string a tu metodo en php y lo guardas en tu BD, para volver a mostrarla luego la decodificas y la agregas a una etiqueta `<img>`

Comment: Tengo entendido que para hacer eso tendría que refrescar la página lo cual estoy evitando, también he intentado codificar la imagen a base 64 desde el input file, poniendola en una etiqueta img y mostrandola con javascript, pero cuando trato de hacer esto varias veces en un slider y trabajando con varios input me deniega el acceso en chrome, por eso es que trato de buscar el método que se emplea en la imagen adjunta